# How to add auth0 authentication to a nextjs 13 application

Tags: javascript, next.js, upgrade, auth0, next.js13

I have a nextjs 12 application and I configured the auth0 as my auth provider following this documentation (https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/nextjs/interactive).
Now I want to upgrade my app to nextjs 13, and I did not found a documentation for this.

Basically with nextjs 12 you have your UserProvider wrapping your app in _app.tsx :

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { UserProvider } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <UserProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </UserProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Now with nextjs 13 changes I have add it to the main page.tsx:

```
import { UserProvider } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client";
import "../styles/globals.css";

export default function RootLayout({
  // Layouts must accept a children prop.
  // This will be populated with nested layouts or pages
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <UserProvider>
        <body>{children}</body>
      </UserProvider>
    </html>
  );
}
```

The problem is that when I call 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login' I get this error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://domain.eu.auth0.com/authorize?client_id=test_number&scope....' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

To mention that in auth0 dashboard I added: http://localhost:3000, https://domain.eu.auth0.com as Allowed Origins CQRS and Allowed Web Origins.

Any thoughts related to this? Has anyone tried to add auth0 to a nextjs 13 app? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the currently open issue about this topic on Github, they will work on supporting the app directory when the app directory is stable.

But as a workaround, you can do it like this:

```
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';


const getUser = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.AUTH0_BASE_URL}/api/auth/me`, {
    headers: {
      cookie: `appSession=${cookies().get('appSession')?.value}`
      // cookie: cookies().getAll().map(c => `${c.name}=${c.value}`).join(';') -- all cookies
    }
  })
  return await res.json()
}

const Home = async () => {
  const user = await getUser();

  return (
    <p>
      {JSON.stringify(user)}
      <br/>
      <a href="/api/auth/login">LOG IN</a>
    </p>
  )
};

export default Home
```

[NextJS 13: support for server-side components in nextjs-auth0](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/issues/889)